# VBA Excel Range to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a range of cells into another range indicating the first cells. Something like that:

```
.Cells(1,1) = .Range("B1:B5")
```

Some help please, it doesn't work and I'm completely new in VBA Excel!

Comment: `.Range("B1:B5").Copy .Cells(1,1)`

Comment: Could it be without usign copy functions? It's a really huge workbook and I need to copy a huge amount of data, and I've read that is no a good idea using this function.

Comment: It also copy with format...

Comment: you could use 1) `Set rng = .Range("B1:B5")` and then 2) `.Cells(1, 1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = .Range("B1:B5").Value`. Or without defining new variable:`.Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Range("B1:B5").Rows.Count, .Range("B1:B5").Columns.Count).Value = .Range("B1:B5").Value`

Comment: Simoco's reply answers the question perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to copy or to where, but...

```
With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = .Range("B1").value
End With
```

will copy the contents of Cell B1 to Cell A1 on the same page.  If you need to copy the 5 cells in the Range B1:B5 you need to specify a range as your first argument.  You can do so as such:

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(5, 1).Address).value = .Range("B1:B5").value
```

Which will copy the contents of B1 to B5 over to A1 to A5.

Excel treats any number of cells inside a workbook be it 1 or 20 or more as a range, Cells lets you reference a single cell only.  When you need to specify a range like `Range("B1:B5")` you can find the cells that define it and use `.Address` to get their string formatted range address.  So `Cells(1, 1).Address` returns `"$A$1"` and conatenating these in a range reference will get you a range so long as you remember the ":" in the middle.

Hope that helps.